# jQuery - How to destroy an event which is attached to an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, mouseup

I have some line of codes which will move an element to mouse position after it is `mousedown`-ed.

I want to remove the event attached to it, so it won't following the mouse position anymore after it is `mouseup`-ed!

#### The Problem

The element still follows the mouse after `mouseup`!

I want it to follow the mouse on `mousedown` and stop following the mouse after `mouseup`! How do I remove the `mousemove` listener from the element?

Here is the **JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".crossY").on("mousedown", function (e) {
        var j = $(this);
        $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
            j.css({
                "top": e.pageY,
                "left": e.pageX
            });
        });
    })

    $(".crossY").on("mouseup", function (e) {
        var j = $(this);
        $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
            j.css({
                "top": j.css("top"),
                "left": j.css("left")
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and the **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9d7ut5y/11/)**

Comment: Although it may seem like the way to do this is to bind/unbind a handler, that takes a good bit more overhead than simply binding a single `mousemove` handler *outside* the `mousedown/up` events and having its behavior changed based on a shared variable.

Comment: ...like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v9d7ut5y/16/ I also put the `mouseup` on the `document` because it can be that the pointer isn't directly on the moved element when you mouseup. You can experiment both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove a mouse listener, you need to use the jQuery `.off` method. In order to get this to work easily, you should namespace the `mousemove` event. This will allow you to easily detach the necessary `mousemove` listener.

Inside the `mousedown` we want to attach the listener

```
$(document).on('mousemove.following', function (e) { /* my event handler */ })
```

Inside the `mouseup` we want to detach the listener

```
$(document).off('mousemove.following')
```

The `following` namespace makes sure that no other event listeners are detached.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/v9d7ut5y/14/) of this working (your jsfiddle except updated).

Another thing you might want to do is make the moving part centered underneath the mouse.

```
$(".crossY").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    var j = $(this);
    var height = j.height(), width = j.width();
    $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
        j.css({
            "top": e.pageY - height/2,
            "left": e.pageX - width/2,
        });
    });
})
```

Subtracting half of the element height and width keeps the element centered underneath the mouse, which will also ensure that the `mouseup` even is fired.

Comment: the element is still following the mouse!

Comment: Did you try looking at the JSFiddle?

Comment: I did! my browser is firefox!

Comment: With the moving centered underneath the mouse piece, it works for me in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

try using `bind()` and `unbind()` like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9d7ut5y/15/)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".crossY").on("mousedown", function (e) {
        var j = $(this);
        $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
            j.css({
                "top": e.pageY-10,
                "left": e.pageX-10
            });
        });
    })

    $(".crossY").on("mouseup", function (e) {
        var j = $(this);
        $(document).unbind("mousemove");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(".crossY").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    var j = $(this);
    $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
        j.css({
            "top": e.pageY,
            "left": e.pageX
        });
    });
})

$(".crossY").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    var j = $(this);
    $(document).off("mousemove");
});
```

});